# postgres pg_upgrade 9.2 to 9.5 problem

Tags: postgresql, upgrade

I'm trying to upgrade from 9.2 to 9.5 using the `pg_upgrade` tool.

I'm using CentOS 7.0

```
current postgres bin folder: /opt/rh/postgresql92/root/usr/bin
new postgres bin folder: /opt/rh/rh-postgresql95/root/usr/bin
current data folder: /mnt/postgres/data
new data folder: /mnt/postgres/data95
```

I've set the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/rh/rh-postgresql95/root/usr/lib64`

When I run

```
/opt/rh/rh-postgresql95/root/usr/bin/pg_upgrade --link --check --old-bindir=/opt/rh/postgresql92/root/usr/bin --new-bindir=/opt/rh/rh-postgresql95/root/usr/bin --old-datadir=/mnt/postgres/data --new-datadir=/mnt/postgres/data95
```

I get this message :

```
Performing Consistency Checks
-----------------------------
Checking cluster versions                                   /opt/rh/postgresql92/root/usr/bin/pg_ctl: error while loading shared libraries: libpq.so.postgresql92-5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Could not get pg_ctl version data using "/opt/rh/postgresql92/root/usr/bin/pg_ctl" --version: No such file or directory
Failure, exiting
```

I'm not sure why it is trying to use the 9.2 version of pg_ctl

```
which pg_ctl
```

returns

```
/opt/rh/rh-postgresql95/root/usr/bin/pg_ctl
```

What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the way to resolve this, have `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` with both old and new postgres bin folders

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/rh/postgresql92/root/usr/lib64
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/opt/rh/rh-postgresql95/root/usr/lib64
```

Answer (score 4):

The issue repeated for me on a legacy PostgreSQL 9.2 to 11 upgrade. The pg_upgrade would fail with: FATAL:  unrecognized configuration parameter "unix_socket_directory"

Blog entry at https://altinukshini.wordpress.com/2018/05/03/upgrade-postgres-9-2-to-9-6-in-centos-7-bold-lines/ gives the solution, ditto:

```
mv /usr/bin/pg_ctl{,-orig}
echo '#!/bin/bash' > /usr/bin/pg_ctl
echo '"$0"-orig "${@/unix_socket_directory/unix_socket_directories}"' >>     
   /usr/bin/pg_ctl
chmod +x /usr/bin/pg_ctl
```

Run now the pg_upgrade (as postgres user), the unix_socket_directories error should be gone.
Lastly, (as root) revert:
`mv -f /usr/bin/pg_ctl{-orig,}`